# UWP: Background Tasks - Custom Trigger

Tags: javascript, background, uwp

I am trying to set a custom trigger `setTrigger` for a background task in javascript.

I've thought that using the [`contentChanged` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard_ContentChanged) this ...

```
taskBuilder.setTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.contentChanged);
```

... would work, but it result in the following error message:

> 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetTrigger is expecting a background trigger instance. not a event like a timetrigger. You can't build your own triggers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger

Comment: Is there any other way of achieving the same?

Comment: Clipboard.contentChanged can only be used in the foreground app.

Comment: So the only option would be to use that method in a loop, when the app is in the foreground?